# Calling c# from JS via button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

So what I want to do is click on a button which will cause JS code to run which will cause another button to click and button #2 will be `runat="server"` and cause a C# function to run `onClick`.
But using the below does not cause the C# function to run even though simply clicking the button2 does cause it to run.

```js
function button1_click() {
    document.getElementById('button2').click();
    __doPostBack('#button2', 'onclick');     
    $('#button2').trigger('click');
// neither worked (tried them seperately)
}
```

```html
 <asp:Button runat="server" Visible="true" text="you should not see this" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="button2" onclick="button2_Click" formnovalidate />
```

Useful knowledge:
 - button one is in a client form
 - button two is in a runat="server" form

Comment: I assume you've just not typed the `#` to identify the button by ID and you've also omitted the `ClientIDMode="Static"` part of your markup? If not.. that's probably your issue (hard to tell if thats a typo though..).

Comment: Have you tried `__doPostBack('#button2','OnClick');`

Comment: so
    $('#button2').trigger('click');?
and where do I add the ClientIDMode="Static"?

Comment: @Dan - That should be an attribute of `button2` in your markup. `<asp:Button ID="button2" ClientIDMode="Static"...` etc. Give that a try first - I suspect that will help.

Comment: Didn't work, I edited original post to show my current code

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer artm but doPostBack didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
$('#button2').trigger('click');
```

should work.
Have you checked that the ID 'button2' is not changed during runtime?
Sometimes, when using master pages or user controls, the client ID of an element with `runat="server"` attribute will get a prefix at run time.
Use a debug console (depends on your browser, try pressing F12) to check the effective client ID.

Also, have you checked that `button1_click()` function is actually called?

Comment: The button1 works (checked);
The button2 works (checked);
So seperately there is no problem; But the trigger doesn't work, the id did not change(checked)